# The magrittr `.` pronoun and rlang `.data` pronoun are identical, but how can that be?

Tags: r, rlang, magrittr, tidyeval

[Finally! TidyEval is getting easier](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/), which led me to do a pronoun test between the magrittr `.` pronoun and the rlang pronoun `.data`.

```
library(tidyverse)
identical(head(iris, 2) %>% mutate(col = .$Species),
          head(iris, 2) %>% mutate(col = .data$Species))
#> [1] TRUE
```

Look at that. They are *exactly* the same. Except they're probably not. From the article linked above:

> The . pronoun from magrittr is not appropriate here because it
>   represents the whole data frame, whereas .data represents the subset
>   for the current group.

What are the differences? You're probably thinking, *"Just read that sentence above that you pasted"*. Unfortunately I need a little more explanation if you can provide it. Some kind of examples would be nice. The first thing I thought of trying (code above) show the two pronouns as "identical". I'm sensing a contradiction here. Thank you.

Comment: Since you are using the column from the entire dataset in your example, which is what `.` represents, it will work fine in this case.  You should start seeing the difference once you start grouping.  See, e.g., `iris[c(1, 51), ] %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(col = .$Species)`.

Comment: The `.` is not an exported object from {magrittr}, though `.data` is exported by {rlang}.  I believe `identical()` is looking at the evaluated results.

Comment: the exported `.data` is nothing interesting though : `identical(.data, structure(list(), class = "rlang_fake_data_pronoun"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully this will illustrate the quote in your question :

````
``` r
library(dplyr)
iris[48:52,] %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  transmute(
    Sepal.Length,
    col0 = mean(Sepal.Length),
    col1 = mean(.$Sepal.Length),
    col2 = mean(.data$Sepal.Length))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#> # Groups:   Species [2]
#>   Species    Sepal.Length  col0  col1  col2
#>   <fct>             <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 setosa              4.6  4.97  5.66  4.97
#> 2 setosa              5.3  4.97  5.66  4.97
#> 3 setosa              5    4.97  5.66  4.97
#> 4 versicolor          7    6.7   5.66  6.7 
#> 5 versicolor          6.4  6.7   5.66  6.7
```
````

I think some like to use it to pass arguments as strings without the `!!sym(foo)` gymnastics :

```r
col <- "Species"
iris[48:52,] %>% 
  mutate(
    SPECIES1 = toupper(!!sym(col)),
    SPECIES2 = toupper(.data[[col]]))
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species   SPECIES1
#> 1          4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2     setosa     SETOSA
#> 2          5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2     setosa     SETOSA
#> 3          5.0         3.3          1.4         0.2     setosa     SETOSA
#> 4          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor VERSICOLOR
#> 5          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor VERSICOLOR
#>     SPECIES2
#> 1     SETOSA
#> 2     SETOSA
#> 3     SETOSA
#> 4 VERSICOLOR
#> 5 VERSICOLOR
```

For what it's worth I had to use `.data` maybe 3 times all in all and when I did there was probably a better way to go at it. I think one or two of those where with `ggplot2`.

You can mostly ignore the existence of `.data` and still become a very decent tidyverse ninja.